# Select ONLY row with max(id) in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table A :

```
ID     | ProductCatId | ProductCode | Price
1      |       1      |  PROD0001   | 2
2      |       2      |  PROD0005   | 2
3      |       2      |  PROD0005   | 2
4      |       3      |  PROD0008   | 2
5      |       5      |  PROD0009   | 2
6      |       7      |  PROD0012   | 2
```

I want to select ID,ProductCatId,ProductCode,Price with condition :
**"if ProductCatId exists same value ,so get ProductCatId with max(ID)"**, like :

```
ID     | ProductCatId | ProductCode | Price
1      |       1      |  PROD0001   | 2
3      |       2      |  PROD0005   | 2
4      |       3      |  PROD0008   | 2
5      |       5      |  PROD0009   | 2
6      |       7      |  PROD0012   | 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for window function and row_number()

```
select ID , ProductCatId , ProductCode , Price
  from (
        select ID , ProductCatId , ProductCode , Price, row_number() over (partition by ProductCatId order by ID desc) as rn
         from myTable
        ) as t
  where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
top 1 with ties
ID,ProductCatId,ProductCode,Price
from
table
order by
row_number() over (partition by productcatid order by id desc)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

may use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProductCatId order by ID desc) as seqnum
      from @Table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
Select Max(ID),ProductCatId,ProductCode,price
From TableName
Group By ProductCatId,ProductCode,price
```

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    max(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCatId, 
                               ProductCode, 
                               Price) AS ID,
    ProductCatId, 
    ProductCode, 
    Price,
  FROM myTable
```